# Complexity when loop variable changes for each iteration?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, amortized-analysis

```
A(q, cList){                 
    for(i=1;i<q;i++){       // q is the number of keywords in the query
        B(cList[i]);            
    }
}

B(c){
    for(j=1; j<c;j++){  // c specifies how many times the keyword is included, and taken as input
        do something
    }
}

For example: 
A(2, [5, 7])     // 2 keywords are searched, that are included in 5 and 7 documents
A(2, [100, 1500]) // 2 keywords are searched, that are included in 100 and 1500 documents
A(3, [1, 10000, 1500]) // 3 keywords are searched, that are included in 1, 10000 and 1500 documents
```

The outer loop depends on q. But I don't decide the complexity of B?

**The value of c** changes **for each keyword**.
I think it also depends on the c values.

So, what is the complexity of A?

Comment: It depends on what c changes to each iteration. If it has something to do with `q` it's probably O(n^2), but if it's just a few fixed elements above `j` it's probably O(n).

Comment: Lets think we have q keywords to search, and c is the result length of each keyword. So, is it O(q)? @ggorlen

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to guess O(n) here because there's no relationship between c and q, so if the input size grows, the string sizes don't necessarily increase as well. Curious to hear some other thoughts.

Comment: No, it is misunderstood. Assume we have 2 keywords to search. If first keyword is included 5 documents, then c is 5. If second keyword is included 7 documents, c is 7... @ggorlen

Comment: I don't really follow. Your code example and description are pretty vague--can you do a more concrete explanation in code of what you're looking at? Either way, I'm sticking with O(n) until I see that c and q have some relationship.

Comment: I try to explain it with examples. @ggorlen

Comment: assuming the smallest possible value of `c` to be `min`, the average value of `c` to be `avg` and largest possible value of `c` to be `max`, we could probably express the complexity of A as `omega(q * min)` for best-case complexity, `theta(q * avg)` for average-case complexity and `O(q * max)` as worst-case complexity

Comment: one more formal way is to express worst-case complexity as `O(q * max(cList[i])) where i = 1 -> q-1`. Also note that I ignore `do something` part here, for simplicity

Comment: this one is also an option: `O(cList[1] + cList[2] + ... + cList[i]) where i=q-1`

Answer (score 1):

Here we have 2 inputs that increase the complexity in, for example, input `A(2,[1,100])`. Outer loops iterations will be decided by first parameter of function `A` , which is 2 here, lets call it `n` and as for the second loop in function `B` it's iteration number will be decided by the second parameter of function `A` which is , in this case , `[1,100]`. By these we would calculate the worst-case complexity by `O( n * max(cList[]))` where max here takes the length of the longest element of `cList`.

I was going to call this complexity analysis too pessimistic but when we think asymptotically your run time will be mostly be affected by the max value in `cList`.

Comment: I guess The complexity should be **`O( n * sum(cList[]) )`**.

Comment: Well, don't think  `O(n*sum)` would be correct. Maybe `O(sum(cList[])` would be more probable but with big-Oh here we are trying to get an upperbound. So as I said worst-case should be `O(n*max(cList[]))`.

Comment: Well incase of `A(100, [100, 100, ..., 100])` all values be 100 in array, what will be the complexity? If you say max(cList[]) it will be 100, but sum will be `100*(100+1)/2`,.

Comment: In your example `n` is 100, and maximum element of `cList[]` is also 100. So going with my example it will be `O(n*max(cList[]))` so `100*100`. I don't think `n*sum` makes sense here. Complexity here is in a class of `O(m*n)` what you suggest is a different kind of logic not fit here, I think.

Comment: Also `100 * (100+1) / 2 ` is the summation formula for all numbers from 1 to 100.